# Wait for Android Animation from different Class

Tags: android, animation

my Problem is that i want to wait until my Animation is finished before the Endscreen Activity gets started. The problem is that i call the Animation through a function from another class.

My turn Animations function:

```
public void turn1(View view){
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(DegreesGear1 ,DegreesGear1 + 90 , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setDuration(400);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(rotate);
    DegreesGear1 = DegreesGear1 + 90;
}
public void turn2(View view){
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(DegreesGear2 ,DegreesGear2 + 90 , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setDuration(400);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(rotate);
    DegreesGear2 = DegreesGear2 + 90;
}
```

My onClick function:

```
public void turnGear(View v){
    ImageButton gear1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Gear1);
    if (DegreesGear1 == 360) {
        DegreesGear1 = 0;
    }
    turn1(gear1);
    final TextView viewCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewMoveNumber);
    turnCounter ++;
    viewCounter.setText (String.valueOf(turnCounter));
    if (DegreesGear1 == 180) {
        Intent EndScreen = new Intent (this, EndScreen.class);
        startActivity(EndScreen);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by setting an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) on your animation. Set the listener and in the [onAnimationEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) callback, start the activity.

Edit:
If `turn1` is getting called from multiple places, consider sending the animation listener as parameter to this method so that each caller can set their own listeners.

Comment: I tried this but the Problem is that I have about 6 classes which use the Animation and i only want it to open the Endscreen under certain qualifications, which are different for each of the 6 Classses.

Comment: See the "Edit" part above. Modify `turn1(View view)` to `turn1(View view, Animation.AnimationListener listener)` and then call it from `turnGear()`. For places you don't need to do anything when the animation ends, just pass null and don't set it inside `turn1()`.

Comment: With this suggestion you just solved another Problem of mine i will try some things and tell you if it worked :)

Comment: I cant rly get it to work but you helped a lot!
I added the second Animation I have in Top Post. I try to merge them but dont know how...  Edit: I try to explain me a bit more... I have to ImageButton which should get Rotated. Each button should have it's on "Tracker" so i can see how far he got rotated. My aim is if they are both on 180° the Endscreen should get opened.